# How to calculate and show all left and right child on binary

Tags: php, mysql, binary-tree

I am a new learner in PHP and I am modifying a simple binary site. 
I am here to ask help how can I calculate my downline pairs or the total left and right side of
some user.

Here is the example of my tables in database:

```
    +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    | childID | parentID | position +
    +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    | Admin   | NULL     | NULL     +
    | First   | Admin    | lft      +
    | Second  | Admin    | rgt      +
    | Third   | First    | lft      +
    | Fourth  | First    | rgt      +
    | Fift    | Second   | lft      +
    | Six     | Second   | rgt      +
    | Sevent  | Third    | lft      +
    | Eight   | Third    | rgt      +
    | Ninth   | Fourth   | lft      +
    | Tenth   | Fifth    | rgt      +
```

I have three tables consist of **childID** or their username, **parentID** or their Sponsors/Referral, and
**position** for their position which is lft(left) and rgt(right).

What I am planning to do is, I want to show the user (or childID) their 
total left(lft) and right(rgt) downlines.

For example, I want to get the total of all downlines of the childID (First) from left and right 
base on my table structure and show it to the user (First).

Hope someone can help me about this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will make any solution by modify your script. This will calculate the number of left and right downline in member tree binary tree.

Make a table of member for registration :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `member` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(55) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `upline` varchar(55) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `position` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `sponsor` varchar(55) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `_left` varchar(55) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `_right` varchar(55) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;
```

make table of downline structure :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `net_downline` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `upline` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `level` int(7) NOT NULL,
  `position` varchar(10) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;
```

As get from simple or basic registration form :

```
$newuser        = htmlentities(trim($_POST['user']));
$sponsor        = htmlentities(trim($_POST['sponsor']));    
$upline         = htmlentities(trim($_POST['upline']));
$position       = htmlentities(trim($_POST['position']));
```

During process, this tree steps should be done :

```
// 1. register new member
$users->dummyRegister($newuser, $sponsor, $upline, $position);
// 2. update upline
$users->dummyUpdateUpline($newuser, $upline, $position);

// 3. create donwline structure of binary tree
$level=0;
$memberid=$newuser;
do{
$getdata=$users->dummyGetUpline($memberid); 
$uplne=$getdata[2]; 
$posi=$getdata[3];

$level++;
if($uplne!==''){
$users->dummyInsert_NetDownline($newuser, $uplne, $posi, $level);
}
$memberid=$uplne;
}
while($memberid!='');
```

class "user" for that script :

```
<?php  // statr class

    class Users{

        private $db;
        public function __construct($database) {
            $this->db = $database;
        }   
    public function dummyRegister($username, $sponsor, $upline, $position, $today){

            $query  = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO `member` (`username`, `sponsor`, `upline`, `position`, `entry_date` ) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ");          
            $query->bindValue(1, $username);
            $query->bindValue(2, $sponsor);
            $query->bindValue(3, $upline);
            $query->bindValue(4, $position);
            $query->bindValue(5, $today);

            try{
                $query->execute();
             }catch(PDOException $e){
                die($e->getMessage());
            }   
        }

    public function dummyUpdateUpline($username, $upline, $position){

            if ($position=='left') {
            $query  = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE `member` SET `_left`=? WHERE username=? ");
            }elseif ($position=='right') {
            $query  = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE `member` SET `_right`=? WHERE username=? ");
            }

            $query->bindValue(1, $username);
            $query->bindValue(2, $upline);

            try{
                $query->execute();

            }catch(PDOException $e){
                die($e->getMessage());
            }   
        }

    public function dummyUpdateUpline($username, $upline, $position){

            if ($position=='left') {
            $query  = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE `member` SET `_left`=? WHERE username=? ");
            }elseif ($position=='right') {
            $query  = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE `member` SET `_right`=? WHERE username=? ");
            }

            $query->bindValue(1, $username);
            $query->bindValue(2, $upline);

            try{
                $query->execute();

            }catch(PDOException $e){
                die($e->getMessage());
            }   
        }

    public function dummyUpdateUpline($username, $upline, $position){

            if ($position=='left') {
            $query  = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE `member` SET `_left`=? WHERE username=? ");
            }elseif ($position=='right') {
            $query  = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE `member` SET `_right`=? WHERE username=? ");
            }

            $query->bindValue(1, $username);
            $query->bindValue(2, $upline);

            try{
                $query->execute();

            }catch(PDOException $e){
                die($e->getMessage());
            }   
        }

    public function dummyGetUpline($newuser) {// for demo

            $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `member` WHERE `username`= ?");
            $query->bindValue(1, $newuser);

            try{
                $query->execute();
                $rows = $query->fetch();

                return $rows;//['upline'];

            } catch(PDOException $e){
                die($e->getMessage());
            }
        }

    public function dummyInsert_NetDownline($newuser, $upline, $posi, $level){// for demo

            $query  = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO `net_downline` (`username`, `upline`, `position`, `level` ) VALUES (?, ?, ? ,?) ");
            $query->bindValue(1, $newuser);
            $query->bindValue(2, $upline);
            $query->bindValue(3, $posi);
            $query->bindValue(4, $level);

            try{
                $query->execute();

            }catch(PDOException $e){
                die($e->getMessage());
            }   
        }   

    }// endclass
```

create initial.php and put in top of your regitration php script :

```
<?php  
if(!isset($_SESSION)) { session_start(); }
require 'conn/database.php'; // in folder conn
require 'clas/users.php';   // in folder class
$users      = new Users($db);
} 
?>
```

this to handle database connection (clas/database.php script) :

```
<?php 
$config = array(
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'username'  => 'root',
    'password'  => '',
    'dbname'    => 'sampledatabase'
);

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $config['host'] . ';dbname=' . $config['dbname'], $config['username'], $config['password']);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

From here you can see the structure of membership base on upline in binary tree. Number of downlines can be achieved by counting the query that match the user.

The disadvantage is that the net_downline database will growing fast caused the system will evaluate and re-arrange the structure for any new registration. For level(n) downline level, it UPDATE and creates n records for single new user.

May somebody here has the best system. Please advise.